# Java Swing can I have a not end-end Menubar?

Tags: java, swing

I need to have a layout for my Java Swing desktop application as shown in the attached picture. I would like to have the menubar not be extended to the end on the right side. How can I do this?[image]

Comment: Did you try use a `JPanel` and add `JMenuBar` to `JPanel`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use menubar as JComponent. So you can add it anywhere you want.